# returning to a select point in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I cant get my code to return back to asking the user for their email.

I have tried several things, but cant figure it out. Right now it continues on to the next function.

how can i get my code to return to asking for user email until its set to true?

```
def name_email(name):

correct_email = False
email = str(input('what is your email: '))
print()

try:
    while correct_email == False:
        if '@' in email:
            print('name and email accepted \n')
            print('name: ',name)
            print('email: ',email)
            print()
            correct_email = True 
        else:
            print('email invalid, please try again \n')
            return 
except:
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: not just that, I would use an regular expression to evaluate, whether it's an email address or not; Your program will also accept email addresses, if they contain multiple @ characters, chinese Characters etc.

Comment: what do you mean by regular expression?

Comment: You may have a look at wikipedia for a general description, what regular expressions are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

In python regular expressions are supported by the re module; have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
def name_email(name):
   correct_email = False
   while correct_email == False:
      email = input('what is your email: ')
      if '@' in email:
          print('name and email accepted \n')
          print('name: ',name)
          print('email: ',email)
          correct_email = True 
      else:
          print('email invalid, please try again \n')
   return email
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 2.x use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` because `input()` tries to evaluate whatever you enter.

I think you're using Python 3.x though because of the prints with parentheses. So keep using `input()`

You don't even need to do the if else condition, you can just put it in the while condition.

```
def name_email(name):

    correct_email = False
    email = str(input('what is your email: '))
    print()

    try:
        while '@' not in email:
            print('email invalid, please try again \n')
            email = str(input('what is your email: '))
            #why return if you want it to ask them again?
            #return
    except:
        raise ValueError    

    print('name and email accepted \n')
    print('name: ',name)
    print('email: ',email)
    print()
```

Comment: yes I am using python 3.x, thanks for taking the time to respond

Answer (score 1):

That stray `return` inside your `else` statement is what's causing your problem. Try removing it.